# Tell Angular about custom element

Tags: html, facebook-javascript-sdk, angular7

I am getting this error:

```
   Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
    ':fb:login-button' is not a known element:
    1. If ':fb:login-button' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If ':fb:login-button' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("data-button-type="login_with" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false"></div>
        [ERROR ->]<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></fb:login-button>

      </ma"): ng:///AppModule/MyNavComponent.html@27:4
        at syntaxError (compiler.js:2427)
        at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:20311)
        at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:25857)
        at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:25844)
        at compiler.js:25787
        at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:25787)
        at compiler.js:25697
        at Object.then (compiler.js:2418)
        at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:25696)
```

the error has to do with using this html:

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></fb:login-button>
```

that element is pulled from the basic examples for embedding a fb login into a webpage, which you can see here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/#

does anyone know how to mitigate this error with Angular?

Comment: Don’t know where you got that code from, but the generator under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button generates code that uses `<div class="fb-login-button" …>`, and the examples further down the page do as well.

Comment: @04FS I got the same issue, the mentioned code comes straight from one of the facebook tutorials on their website. I guess it's some kind of javascript trick that isn't compatible with angular.

Comment: did you try adding CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA in your app.module ? to tell angular that you are using components outside of angular